# Read file from sFtp server

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, sftp, spring-batch

I'm reading the file from sftp server and load that file into Database using Spring Batch Framework below is my code but i m getting an Error

Code:

```
<bean id="cvsFileItemReaderMeta" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <!-- Read a csv file -->

    <property name="resource" value= "ftp://scmuser:scmuser%40123@172.18.228.32:22/home/scmuser/CSV/Meta.csv" />
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:306)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:192)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
    at com.tcs.ceg.iforesee.service.DataLoader.loadMetaMapping(DataLoader.java:127)
    at com.tcs.ceg.iforesee.service.UploadFile.uploadFile(UploadFile.java:77)
    at com.tcs.ceg.iforesee.service.UploadFile.main(UploadFile.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode): URL [ftp://username:password@hostname.com:22/home/scmuser/CSV/Meta.csv]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doOpen(FlatFileItemReader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:139)
```

Comment: You wrote about SFTP, yet the URL is `ftp://`. What protocol do you actually want to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339508/spring-batch-how-to-use-spring-batch-to-read-file-from-sftp-server-and-save-it?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: **Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)**: URL [[ftp://username:password@hostname.com:22/home/scmuser/CSV/Meta.csv]](ftp://username%3apassword@hostname.com:22/home/scmuser/CSV/Meta.csv%5d)

Obviously the resource does not exist. You either have to ensure that the resource exists before attempting to open it or unset the reader's strict mode using [FlatFileItemReader#setStrict](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html#setStrict-boolean-) and passing `false`

> In strict mode the reader will throw an exception on AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext) if the input resource does not exist.

Comment: yes i have Checked the input file and aslo i hv setthe strict mode to false but then also its not working

Comment: @user3725690 please update your question with the new error message, I dont think wil be the same since you have set strict mode to false

Comment: No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor. 2014-06-11 18:20:03 INFO SimpleJobLauncher:132 - Job: [FlowJob: [name=meta]] launched with the following parameters: [{time=1402491003252, FileName=Meta.csv}] 2014-06-11 18:20:04 INFO SimpleStepHandler:135 - Executing step: [step1] 2014-06-11 18:24:04 WARN FlatFileItemReader:253 - Input resource does not exist URL [ftp://scmuser:scmuser%40123@172.18.228.32:22/home/scmuser/CSV/Meta.csv]  its saying input resource does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achive your goal and have a better error handling can be divide download+import in 2 step:

1. Retrieve file from FTP (you can handle file missing using a dedicer/exit-status, incomplete file download, etc)
2. Import file from local without care about ftp transfer errors (broken connection in the middle of data import, for example)

Comment: I don't want to download the file  i want to read directly from sftp server

Comment: if so,check @Martin comment below your question