# Spring batch using annotations :- How to read file from server using SFTP and use as resource in MultiResourceItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I am new in spring batch. I am creating a batch job using spring batch through annotations. My goal is:

1. Read the multiple files using `MultiResourceItemReader` from SFTP server.
2. Process the files.
3. Insert the data into database.

Currently I am reading the multiple files from class path using `MultiResourceItemReader` and inserting the data into DB.

But my problem is how to read the file from server using SFTP.

Can someone guide me or give me some working code?

Comment: can you put the code how you re doing it( I am reading the multiple files from class path)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch : How to use spring batch to read file from sftp server and save it into database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339508/spring-batch-how-to-use-spring-batch-to-read-file-from-sftp-server-and-save-it)