# why doesn't spring-batch support write to sftp?

Tags: spring-batch, sftp

I want to read data from mysql, then write to sftp. now i write file to local, from local to sftp, What's the best way?

```
FlatFileItemWriter writer = new FlatFileItemWriter();
writer.setResource(new PathResource("path"));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Batch : How to use spring batch to read file from sftp server and save it into database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339508/spring-batch-how-to-use-spring-batch-to-read-file-from-sftp-server-and-save-it)

Answer (score 0):

Spring Batch writes locally.  From there, you can use Spring Integration to transfer the file once the job is complete.

Comment: one Job is  Spring Batch writes locally
another Job is Spring Integration to transfer the file?